# Facebook messenger webview not allow to access camera and audio

Tags: webview, webrtc, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am developing a messenger chat bot, user get a doctor consultation url via bot.

Here is the payload I have use

```
"message": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "generic",
        "elements": [
          {
            "title": "Dr.ABC has initiaed the call. Click on the Call below to Join.",
            "subtitle": "NOTE: This link will expire in 30 minutes.",
            "image_url": "https://doctorconsult.com/images/doc.jpg",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "type": "web_url",
                "title": "Call",
                "url": "https://doctorconsult.com/patientconversation/665161e3-0f50-4930-aefb-404d5c3f584f",
                "webview_height_ratio": "full",
                "messenger_extensions": true,
                "webview_share_button": "HIDE"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
 }
```

this send the web_url for doctor consultation URL ( that need access camera and audio ) when we open up URL in a browser this works, but when I open url using bot button click, it doesn't not allow camera and  audio. How do we allow to access camera and audio to "https://doctorconsult.com/" in messenger web view ?

I am getting permission issue when its loading inside messenger web view when accessing media

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(this.videoConstraints).then(stream => {
      this.localStream = stream;
      this.localVideoPlayer.srcObject = stream;
      this.localMediaReady = true;
      this.socketService.emitCallingToPatient({
        customerCode: this.conversation.customerCode,
        currentConversationCallId: this.currentConversationCallId
      });
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior due to limitations applied to webviews loaded via the in-app-browser/Messenger/Facebook app.